# Reading off a text list and copying files from another folder using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to read off a .txt file that contains a list of names of .jpgs I want from another directory, and then copy those files to the current directory. The name of the text file can't be hardcoded, as I intend to use the same batch file for hundreds of folders, each with their own unique .txt list.

I've tried this:

```
FOR /F %%a in ("*.txt") do (
    FOR /F "delims=" %%N in (%%a) do COPY "C:\Files\%%N.jpg" %cd%
)
```

The second For loop works when used in isolation with a hardcoded .txt.

Sorry if it's a newbie mistake, I'm new to cmd line.

Comment: The `/F` option is used to read a file.  Why are you using /D?

Comment: Woops, I think that was from a previous attempt. Changed it to /F, however still does not work. I think it's somehow taking "*.txt" as a literal, as it returns "*.txt" rather than the name of the .txt file in the cmd

Comment: That's exactly what it's doing. Check out the output of `for /?` again. When `usebackq` isn't listed as an option, double quotes are for processing strings, single quotes are for processing commands, and no quotes are for processing files.

Comment: I used this to check the first loop:

```For %%a in (*.txt) do (echo %%a)```

And it returns the filename correctly. When the exact same filename is used as a hardcoded value for %%a in the second loop, it also works. However when used together, it still seems to not work. Currently I'm using no quotes surrounding anything with %%a.

Comment: What's the problem with calling every text file `filelist.txt`, or something more obscure like `files.list`? There's no reason to give every file a completely different, and therefore unknown name!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that, and that's what my code reads: the first and only .txt file in the folder. It's just that I also eventually might want to put every .txt in the same folder and iterate on all of them, where the same name wouldn't work. Anyway I found the solution, see below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an alternative, using just a single loop:

For [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd):

```sh
For /F "EOL=? Tokens=*" %G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "^" *.txt') Do @Copy /Y "C:\Files\%~G.jpg"
```

For [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file):

```sh
@For /F "EOL=? Tokens=*" %%G In ('%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe "^" *.txt') Do @Copy /Y "C:\Files\%%~G.jpg"
```

BTW, your own code should look more like this, *(using `UseBackQ` as advised in the comments)*, especially if their names contain problematic characters:

For [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)

```sh
For %G In (*.txt) Do @For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=*" %H In ("%G") Do @Copy /Y "C:\Files\%~H.jpg"
```

For [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

```sh
@For %%G In (*.txt) Do @For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=*" %%H In ("%%G") Do @Copy /Y "C:\Files\%%~H.jpg"
```

---

*You'll note that in both example types I've omitted the destination directory, which will default to the current directory when you do so.*

Answer (score 0):

I found the syntax that works:

```
For %%a in (*.txt) do (
    For /f "delims=" %%N in (%%a) do COPY "C:\Files\%%N.jpg" %cd%
)
```